# AWS push notification click not working when app is in killed state

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, push-notification, aws-amplify

Currently using this function for react-native android app

```
    PushNotification.onNotificationOpened(notification => {
        console.log("on notification opened", notification);
   });
```

This will work when app is in background. When in killed state, clicking notification just opens app.

Comment: Any solutions you found?

Comment: I had to edit the library and place the notification object in a global value during app launch. I found no other way. Sorry.

Comment: @HGK Can you please elaborate where and how did you make changes? I am also going through same problem.

Comment: guys, any solution for this. I am facing the same issue. Fighting from couple of days. :(